# jQuery not finding class after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I have essentially a cart section where a user should be able to remove items from the cart and then the contents are refreshed with AJAX. However, after a cart item is removed the response changes from asynchronous to synchronous and I can't establish why.

Sorry new to programming so a lot of things may not be the best way to do something, any help appreciated!

Views.py

```
def checkout_detail_api_view(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    items = order.cartItems_set.all()

    '# create lists for items to be put in dictionary' 
    productId_list = []
    product_url = []
    productName_list = []
    location_list = []
    img_list = []

    checkoutList = {}
    for item in items:
        '# append into lists'
        productId_list.append(item.product_id)
        productName_list.append(item.product.title)
        product_url.append(item.product.get_absolute_url())
        img_list.append(item.product.image.url)
        location_list.append(item.product.location)

    checkoutList["id"] = productId_list
    checkoutList["title"] = productName_list
    checkoutList["location"] = location_list
    checkoutList["image"] = img_list
    checkoutList["url"] = product_url

    checkout_data = {"checkoutList": checkoutList}
    return JsonResponse(checkout_data)



def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    customer = request.user.customer

    if product_id is not None:
        try:

            product_title = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
            
        except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
            print("Show message to user, product is gone?")

    '# gets or makes product order'
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    '# gets or makes cartItem'
    cartItem, created = cartItems.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product_obj)    

    '# gets all items in cart '
    items = order.cartItems_set.all()
    
    '# for each item in cart remove quantity, else add quantity'
    for item in items:
        
        '# remove (max quantity of 1)'
        if int(product_id) == int(item.product_id) and item.quantity >= 1:
            cartItem.quantity = 0
            product_added = False
        '# Add '   
        elif int(product_id) == int(item.product_id):
            cartItem.quantity = 1
            product_added = True

    cartItem.save()

    if cartItem.quantity <= 0:
        cartItem.delete()

    '#reinitialize cart items after updating above'
    items = order.cartItem_set.all()
    cartItemCount = items.count()
    
    '# this is not being called on second attempt of removing item from cart'
    if request.is_ajax(): 
        
       json_data = {
            "added": product_added,
            "removed": not product_added,
            "cartItemCount": cartItemCount
    }
    return JsonResponse(json_data)

    '# if request is not ajax redirect page - this is being called and I dont know why'
    return redirect("/see-and-do/checkout")

def checkout(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    items = order.cartItem_set.all()
    cartItems = items.count()

    productId_list = []
    productName_list = []
    location_list = []

    for item in items:
        '# append into lists'
        productId_list.append(item.product_id)
        productName_list.append(item.product.title)
        location_list.append(item.product.location)

checkoutList = dict(zip(items, location_list))
context = {'checkoutList':checkoutList, 'cartItems': cartItems}
return render(request, 'posts/checkout.html', context)`
```

checkout.html

```
{%  if cartItems > 0 %}
      <div class="table-responsive">          
        <table class="table cart-table">
           <tbody class="cart-body">
            {% for cartItem, location in checkoutList.items %}
            <tr class="cart-product1">
              <td rowspan="2"><img src="{{cartItem.product.image.url}}"></td>
              <td><h5><b>{{cartItem.product.title}}</b></h5></td>
              <td>
                <form class='form-product-ajax' method="POST" action="/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/" data-endpoint="/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/" > {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class='cart-item-product-id' type='hidden' name='product_id' value = '{{ cartItem.product.id}}' />
                    <button type="submit" id="remove-btn">
                        <i class="bi bi-dash"> </i>
                    </button>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cart-product2">
              <td><small class="text-muted">{{location}}</small></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
      
      {% else %}
      <p class='lead'>No products added</p>
      {% endif %}
```

js.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax")
        
        productForm.submit(function(event){
            
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var thisForm = $(this)
            var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("data-endpoint")
            var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
            var formData = thisForm.serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: actionEndpoint,
                method: httpMethod,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data){
                   
                    var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
                    if (data.added) {
                        submitSpan.html(
                            '<button type="submit" id="remove-btn" style="background-color:#ff3333;"><i class="bi bi-dash"> </i><span class="tooltip-text">Remove item</span></button>'
                            )
                    } else {
                        submitSpan.html(
                            '<button type="submit" id="add-btn"><i class="bi bi-plus-square"> </i><span class="tooltip-text">Add to your enquiry</span></button>'
                            )
                    }
                    var navbarCount = $(".navbar-cart-count")
                    navbarCount.text(data.cartItemCount)
                 
                    var currentPath = window.location.href
                    
                    if (currentPath.indexOf("checkout") != -1) {
                        refreshCheckout()
                    }
                },
                error:function(errorData){
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(errorData)
                }


            })
        })

        function refreshCheckout(){
            
            var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
            var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
            var productRowOne = cartBody.find(".cart-product1")
            var productRowTwo = cartBody.find(".cart-product2")

            var currentUrl = window.location.href
            
            

            var refreshCheckoutUrl = '/see-and-do/api/checkout/';
            var updateCheckoutMethod = "GET";
            var data = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: refreshCheckoutUrl,
                method: updateCheckoutMethod,
                data: data,
            success: function(data){
                
                
                
                if (data.checkoutList.id.length > 0) {
                    //remove current checkout.html for AJAX response
                    productRowOne.html(" ")
                    productRowTwo.html(" ")
                    
                
                    $.each(data.checkoutList.id , function(index){
     
                        //prepends everything inside the for loop shown in checkout.html
                        cartBody.prepend("<tr class=\"cart-product1\"><td rowspan=\"2\"><a href ='" + data.checkoutList.url[index] + "'><img src=" + '"' + data.checkoutList.image[index] + '"' + "></a></td><td><h5><b><a href ='" + data.checkoutList.url[index] + "'>"  + data.checkoutList.title[index] + "</a></b></h5></td><td><form class=\"form-product-ajax\" method=\"POST\" action=\"/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/\" data-endpoint=\"/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/\">" + '{% csrf_token %}' + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"product_id\" value =" + '"' + data.checkoutList.id[index] + '"' + "/><button type=\"submit\" id=\"remove-btn\"><i class=\"bi bi-dash\"> </i></button></form></td></tr><tr class=\"cart-product2\"><td><small class=\"text-muted\">" + data.checkoutList.location[index] + "</small></td><td></td></tr>")
                        
                        
                    })
                    
                    
                } else {
                    window.location.href = currentUrl
                }
                
                
            },
            error: function(errorData){
                console.log("checkout error")
                console.log(errorData)
            }
            
        })
    }
})
</script>
```

So everything works for the first run of the script but when I click again it just reloads the entire page via the cart_update view.py due to the response not being AJAX, but I don't understand why it wouldn't be AJAX, I assume because it isn't finding the ".form-product-ajax" after it is prepended in the response?

-- edit --

The other time I use this form is in the product index page. This is where span is involved.

```
<form class='form-product-ajax' method="POST" action="/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/" data-endpoint="/see-and-do/checkout/cart-update/"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value = '{{ product.id}}' />
    <span class="submit-span">
    {% if product.id in productId_list %}
        <button type="submit" id="remove-btn">
        <i class="bi bi-dash"> </i>
        <span class="tooltip-text">Remove item</span>
        </button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="add-btn">
        <i class="bi bi-plus-square"> </i>
        <span class="tooltip-text">Add to your enquiry</span>
        </button>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: HI, where is `submit-span` ?

Comment: @swati - I use submit span on the product index page, so I can change the form button to add or remove, but since I only want remove on the checkout page I have removed it. I have edited the post to include the form if you want to see it.

Comment: can you change event handler like this : `$(document).on("submit", ".form-product-ajax", function(event) { //your codes ..})` see if that works

Comment: @Swati Legend, that got it to work, thanks a lot

Comment: your welcome .. just for reason why that was not working because your form was created dynamically so you need to bind it with static element which is already present in your dom :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try preventing the default behavior of the buttons by using `event.preventDefault();` and performing a form submit via Jquery on button press. Check [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: This is already in the JS.html code in the first few lines but for some reason it is not being triggered once the refreshCheckout function is called and the form within checkout.html is replaced. The .form-product-ajax is in this new form, it just seems the JavaScript is not finding it after it has been replaced?